# regex to find word that starts with c and ends with o

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to write some code to find sentence that has any word that has a letter c followed by a another letter and ends in o. e.g. cxo, ceo, cfo
Aplogies should have mentioned that it can only have one letter in the middle of c and o

I've tried

```
("c.o")
```

but this does not seem to work. Please give me some help on where I am going wrong

Some examples.

`["chrome", "commo", "cron"]` - These should not show

`["cxo", "cfo", "coo", "cho"]` - These should show

Comment: Can you add the code to the question that did not work so readers have more context.

Comment: Example input strings and expected matches would be helpful in giving an exact regex for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to find any 3-letter word starting with C and ending with O, you can insert a **word boundary** `\b` before and after your match like so: `/\bc\wo\b/`. The presence of `\b` will prevent partial matches like `echo` from matching your regex, but will still allow for matches to occur at the beginning and end of your match string.

As an example with python:

```py
import re
r = re.compile(r"\bc\wo\b")
print(r.search("at the end a ceo"))       # => match
print(r.search("ceo at the start"))       # => match
print(r.search("in the middle a ceo is")) # => match
print(r.search("fooceobar"))              # => no match
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work when I tested it some how

Comment: Updated answer with Python example to demonstrate what cases it is aiming to match

Comment: This also matches c[0-9]o .

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution:

```
import re
re.findall('o\wc', your_string)
```

Comment: Thansk for this. This is good but we only want one letter to be allowed in the middle

Answer (score 0):

`\.*c.o` <- starts with c has an Char in between and ends with o